# EVENT_REGISTER_TABLE_ATTRIBUTES not working in Craft 3

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I am developing a plugin to add custom column to entries table for which I am using `EVENT_REGISTER_TABLE_ATTRIBUTES` and `EVENT_SET_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE_HTML` and code example is:

```
Event::on(
    Element::class, 
    Element::EVENT_REGISTER_TABLE_ATTRIBUTES, 
    function(craft\events\RegisterElementTableAttributesEvent $e) {
        return array(
            'foo' => "Foo",
            'bar' => "Bar",
        );
});
Event::on(
    Entry::class, 
    Element::EVENT_SET_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE_HTML, 
    function(craft\events\SetElementTableAttributeHtmlEvent $e) {
        if ($e->attribute === 'foo') {
            return 'bar';
        }
});
```

Unfortunately, its not working. Could anyone please help what I am mistaking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to return anything in an event. As you can see how the Event is triggert

```
Event::trigger(static::class, self::EVENT_REGISTER_TABLE_ATTRIBUTES, $event);
```

It does not expect any return value. So you don't add something by returning an array. Instead you'll have to manipulate the properties of your `event`

When you take a look at your `RegisterElementTableAttributesEvent` it contains the following property

```
/**
 * @var array List of registered table attributes for the element type.
 */
public $tableAttributes = [];
```

In order to add attributes you have to do

```
Event::on(
    Element::class,
    Element::EVENT_REGISTER_TABLE_ATTRIBUTES,
    function(craft\events\RegisterElementTableAttributesEvent $e) {
        $e->tableAttributes['foo'] = [
            'label' => "Foo"
        ];
});
```

It's the same for your `SetElementTableAttributeHtmlEvent`. It has the properties

```
// Properties
// =========================================================================

/**
 * @var array|null The table attribute associated with this event.
 */
public $attribute;

/**
 * @var string|null The HTML to represent a table attribute.
 */
public $html;
```

You can `var_dump` the `$event` to see the current properties to get to know which structure you have to include. Usually you would do

```
Event::on(
    Entry::class,
    Element::EVENT_SET_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE_HTML,
    function(craft\events\SetElementTableAttributeHtmlEvent $e) {
        if($e->attribute === 'foo'){
            $e->html = 'FOOOOO';
        }
    }
);
```