# Custom plugin field in Table Columns?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, custom-fieldtype

I just created my first Craft 3 plugin. In the plugin I also have a custom (select)field. Everything is working as expected, which is great!
But I can't for the life of me figure out, how to add this field as a Table Column? It's not showing up. The field is added and filled in the entries within the section. Just to be clear, this is where I mean:

[image: Table Columns]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question well, you need to use the `EVENT_REGISTER_TABLE_ATTRIBUTES` event. [This thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/25335/3630) should get you on your way :)